# What is the latest postgres version compatible with Keycloak 20

Tags: keycloak

Is there a postgres and keycloak version compatibility matrix?  What is the latest postgres version compatible with Keycloak 20 ?

Answer (score 2):

Postgres is backwards-compatible, so Postgres 15 generally will work with app designed for Postgres 10.

We're running Keycloak 20 with Postgres 15 and didn't run into any issues so far, if you need some anec-data.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no any matrix. In docs just a short and outdated [list](https://www.keycloak.org/server/db#_supported_databases) and some comments in Github discussions on [why](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/10767#issuecomment-1072228348) it's outdated.

Meanwhile, DB version for Java apps always depends on JDBC driver version.
So, the easiest way to find out what version of PostgreSQL is suitable for KC release is to take a look at versions of JDBC driver and PostgreSQL that specified in **pom.xml**. Switch to a release tag in the official repository, e.g. https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/20.0.3/pom.xml#L149-L150

Answer (score 0):

The documentation [here](https://www.keycloak.org/server/db) suggests Version 10.

Comment: that would be quite strange as postgres 10.12 has reached its EOF in Nov 2022 (https://endoflife.software/applications/databases/postgresql#10-12)

Answer (score 0):

The developer commits and issues only mention postgresql without versions. It doesn't matter which version you use, as long as it's supported!

See here for supported versions:
[Supported versions](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)

Answer (score 0):

I am using KC 21.1.2 fine with PG 15